# Connecting Azure Active Directory to VSTS fails

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have followed the steps on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/connect-account-to-aad?view=vsts to get my VSTS instance to use Azure Active Directory. When I click "Connect" I get the error:

> Account [VSTS instance name] connection to an AAD Tenant failed due to
>   the error : Aad guest user cannot be made an owner of the account.
>   Owner identity: (id: [id]; mid: [id]; cuid: [id])

Looking through the list of users I can see that I am logged in as a user that is present on both VSTS and AAD, and that the AAD user has a User Type = Member

Originally the user was setup as Guest, and using powershell I changed them to Member. This seemed to change the user type immediately, but I still get the error above, even after waiting approx. 36 hours so far.

Is there something else I need to do here?

Comment: I have managed to fix this by dropping the user completely and creating a brand new MSA account and starting again. I don't what I did wrong the first time round, but it is working now with the brand new user.

Comment: Hi @Slicc, you can post this comment as answer and accept it. It may be helpful to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above:

I have managed to fix this by dropping the user completely and creating a brand new MSA account and starting again. I don't know what I did wrong the first time round, but it is working now with the brand new user.